# How do I rebind Y to yank to the end of the line when using VS Code's Vim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm using VS Code's neovim integration with neovim installed from `snap`. I want `Y` to work the same way as `D` and `C`. In `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` I would add

```
map Y y$
```

How do I do this in VS Code? I've tried

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["Y"],
            "after": ["y$"]
        },
    ],
```

and

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["Y"],
            "after": ["y$"]
        }
    ],
```

but neither worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out you need to [specify and separate](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6147#issuecomment-779686273) each key into an individual `""`, so that would be:

```json
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["Y"],
        "after": ["y", "$"]
    }
]
```